# C++ HEAP CORRUPTION DETECTED - CRT

Tags: c++, new-operator

I have a BYTE array as follows:

```
BYTE* m_pImage;
m_pImage = new BYTE[m_someLength];
```

And at various stages of my program data is copied to this array like so:

```
BYTE* pDestinationBuffer = m_pImage + m_imageOffset;
memcpy( pDestinationBuffer, (BYTE*)data, dataLength );
```

But when I go to delete my buffer like so:

```
delete[] m_pImage;
```

I am getting the 
**HEAP CORRUPTION DETECTED - CRT detected that the application wrote to memory after the end of heap buffer**

Now I have experimented with a simple program to try and replicate the error in order to help me investigate whats going on.   I see from that following that if I create an array of size 5 but write over the end of it and try to delete it I get the exact same error.

```
int* myArray = new int[5];
myArray[0] = 0;
myArray[1] = 1;
myArray[2] = 2;
myArray[3] = 3;
myArray[4] = 4;
myArray[5] = 5; // writing beyond array bounds

delete[] myArray;
```

Now my question is how can I possibly debug or find out what is overwriting my original buffer.  I know that something is overwriting the end of the buffer, so is there a way for visual studio to help me debug this easily.

The code above that is copying to the data buffer is called several times before the delete soits hard to keep a track of the m_pImage contents and the data copied to it. (Its about 2M worth of data)

Comment: You could use a tool like valgrind to locate the error.  You could also check for `m_imageOffset + dataLength  <= m_someLength`. Fundamentally, you are paying the price for using raw arrays rather than `std::vector`.

Comment: `m_pImage + m_imageOffset + dataLength` is going to be `> m_someLength`

Comment: There's memory breakpoints in visual studio, you could try to set one to the very end of the buffer

Comment: Windows 7 with Visual Studio 2012

Comment: Even without a visual debugger, you could wrap your memcpy operation to catch the condition pointed out by @marc-b

Comment: The problem was that I was increasing m_imageOffset by one every loop.  I didnt need to do this.  I found this by using the suggestions above.  Thanks dudes :)

Comment: @Harry why are you using raw memory allocations?

Answer (score 3):

> Now my question is how can I possibly debug or find out what is overwriting my original buffer.

I would recommend to use `assert()` statement as much as possible. In this case it should be:

```
BYTE* pDestinationBuffer = m_pImage + m_imageOffset;
assert( dataLength + m_imageOffset <= m_someLength );
memcpy( pDestinationBuffer, (BYTE*)data, dataLength );
```

then compile into debug mode and run. Benefit of this method - you will not have any overhead in release mode, where asserts are not evaluated.

Comment: Surely it would be way cleaner to use `std::vector` and avoid re-inventing the wheel

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Actually I doubt `std::vector` will help in this case, data in `std::vector` would go out of bounds exactly the same way, if logical error would not be fixed

Comment: Debug MSVC runtime has bounds checking for `std::vector` unless I'm mistaken

Comment: @DavidHeffernan even for access through iterator?

Comment: I expect so. I think the debug runtime is pretty careful to trap out of bounds errors with standard containers.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan probably so, but that recommendation would not be universal. OP may use STLPort etc, or may not be able to use STL containers at all.

Comment: Denying yourself the STL is pretty much pointless. Still, if you'd prefer to use raw memory allocation and spray code as per you answer into your codebase, that is your choice.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I do not deny STL, I just answering the question and I accept the fact that OP may have reasons to allocate memory manually. He needs to catch logical error in his code, using side effect of particular STL implementation on VS for me is not the best way. That just IMHO.

Answer (score 1):

On Windows you can use the [Application Verifier](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd371695(v=vs.85).aspx) to find this kind of overwrite

Comment: OMG the Application Verifier is so practical. How is it possible that I haven't seen any recommendation before? It adds read/write access checks similar to those present in STL containers to other places. No more wondering where the bug is!

Answer (score 1):

Heap corruption is a tough bug to find.  Most times, when the error is reported, the memory has already been corrupted by some up stream code that executed previously.  If you decide to use Application Verifier (and you should), I'd also encourage you to try [GFLags and PageHeap](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff549561(v=vs.85).aspx).  They are some additional tools that allow you to set registry flags for debugging these types of problems.